My kernel-module dont hook systems-calls, how fix that?
Code of kernel-module
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kprobes.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static void my_write_cr0(long value) {
    __asm__ volatile("mov %0, %%cr0" :: "r"(value) : "memory");
}

#define disable_write_protection() my_write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~0x10000))
#define enable_write_protection() my_write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x10000)

unsigned long* sys_call_table_address;
asmlinkage int (*original_chmod)(const char __user*, umode_t);

static struct kprobe kp = {
    .symbol_name = "kallsyms_lookup_name"
};

typedef unsigned long (*kallsyms_lookup_name_t)(const char* name);

unsigned long* get_sys_call_table_address(void) {
    kallsyms_lookup_name_t kallsyms_lookup_name;
    int ret = register_kprobe(&kp);
    if (ret < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "InterceptChmod: register_kprobe failed, returned %d\n", ret);
        return NULL;
    }
    kallsyms_lookup_name = (kallsyms_lookup_name_t)kp.addr;
    unregister_kprobe(&kp);
    if (!kallsyms_lookup_name) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "InterceptChmod: kallsyms_lookup_name not found\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    unsigned long* address = (unsigned long*)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");
    if (!address) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "InterceptChmod: sys_call_table not found\n");
    }
    else {
        printk(KERN_INFO "InterceptChmod: sys_call_table address: %p\n", address);
    }
    return address;
}

asmlinkage int custom_chmod(const char __user* filename, umode_t mode) {
    char fname[256];

    // Copy the filename from user space to kernel space
    if (strncpy_from_user(fname, filename, sizeof(fname)) > 0) {
        fname[sizeof(fname) - 1] = '\0'; // Ensure null termination
        printk(KERN_INFO "InterceptChmod: chmod intercepted for file: %s, mode: %o\n", fname, mode);
    }
    else {
        printk(KERN_INFO "InterceptChmod: chmod intercepted, failed to get filename, mode: %o\n", mode);
    }

    // Call the original chmod system call
    return original_chmod(filename, mode);
}

static int __init intercept_chmod_init(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "InterceptChmod: Loading module\n");

    sys_call_table_address = get_sys_call_table_address();
    if (!sys_call_table_address) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "InterceptChmod: Failed to get sys_call_table_address\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "InterceptChmod: sys_call_table address: %p\n", sys_call_table_address);

    original_chmod = (void*)sys_call_table_address[__NR_chmod];
    printk(KERN_INFO "InterceptChmod: Original chmod address: %p\n", original_chmod);

    disable_write_protection();
    sys_call_table_address[__NR_chmod] = (unsigned long)custom_chmod;
    enable_write_protection();

    printk(KERN_INFO "InterceptChmod: Hooked chmod system call, new address: %p\n", (void*)sys_call_table_address[__NR_chmod]);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit intercept_chmod_exit(void) {
    if (sys_call_table_address) {
        disable_write_protection();
        sys_call_table_address[__NR_chmod] = (unsigned long)original_chmod;
        enable_write_protection();
        printk(KERN_INFO "InterceptChmod: Restored original chmod system call, address: %p\n", (void*)sys_call_table_address[__NR_chmod]);
    }

    printk(KERN_INFO "InterceptChmod: Module unloaded\n");
}

module_init(intercept_chmod_init);
module_exit(intercept_chmod_exit);

I using Linux 6.8.11-amd64, OracleVM VirtualBox and X86_64 processor.
I load module by using:
sudo insmod lkm_chmod.ko
And then i testing his using command
sudo chmod 755 testfile and he don log this.
My log look like this.
[ 9245.540511] InterceptChmod: Loading module
[ 9245.561100] InterceptChmod: sys_call_table address: 00000000d760dd16
[ 9245.561105] InterceptChmod: sys_call_table address: 00000000d760dd16
[ 9245.561106] InterceptChmod: Original chmod address: 0000000014a7fad1
[ 9245.561110] InterceptChmod: Hooked chmod system call, new address: 00000000ce1988d5
[ 9330.452750] InterceptChmod: Restored original chmod system call, address: 0000000014a7fad1
[ 9330.452766] InterceptChmod: Module unloaded

I cant understand why he dont work, i have no error in log. I tried change __NR_chmod to __NR_open or __NR_close, and he doesn't work.
I tried use ChatGPT, and he talks only nonsense and just repeats my code.

Which kernel version? For v6.9 onwards, x86-64 uses a switch statement to handle system calls, bypassing sys_call_table entirely. sys_call_table still contains the addresses of the system call handler functions, but it is only used for tracing purposes.

I using Linux 6.8.11-amd64

The change has been backported to some stable kernel series: v6.8.5+, v6.6.26+, v6.1.85+, and v5.15.154+.

Thank you @ian-abbott i fix code. You helped me a lot, and in the end I came to the correct answer

Ok i found solution in this answer answer. And thanks Ian Abbott for pointing out that in version 6.9 and older sys_call_table no longer works.
Now i fixed code, and he starting working using kprobes.
#include <linux/kprobes.h>
#include <linux/ptrace.h>

static int sys_read_kprobe_pre_handler(struct kprobe* p, struct pt_regs* regs)
{
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "ROOTKIT: read(%ld, 0x%lx, 0x%lx)\n", regs->di, regs->si, regs->dx);
    return 0;
}

struct kprobe syscall_kprobe = {
    .symbol_name = "__x64_sys_read",
    .pre_handler = sys_read_kprobe_pre_handler,
};

static int __init startup(void)
{
    int err;

    err = register_kprobe(&syscall_kprobe);
    if (err) {
        pr_err("register_kprobe() failed: %d\n", err);
        return err;
    }
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "ROOTKIT: Starting of due");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit shutdown(void)
{
    unregister_kprobe(&syscall_kprobe);
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "ROOTKIT: Ending");
}

module_init(startup);
module_exit(shutdown);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");


And i change chmod to read
